# How to construct a matrix satisfying two semidefinite constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, convex-analysis

You are given matrices $A$, $B$ and $C$.  $C$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite.  How would you go about constructing a matrix $X \succeq 0$ such that $X \succeq AXA^T$ and $C \succeq BXB^T$?  The first can be satisfied by starting with any $X_0 \succeq 0$ and iterating $X_{t+1} = X_0 + AX_tA^T$, but I have no idea how to satisfy both.